# Adding a property to all $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a good way to add a property (in this particular case, it's a service) to all `$scope`s?

To clarify: I have a service called `i18nService`, and I want to use it on angular expressions on the DOM, without having to add it as a dependency to every controller and do something like `$scope.i18nService = i18nService`.

I have been doing this, though I think there should be a better way:

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, i18nService){
    Object.getPrototypeOf($rootScope).i18nService = i18nService;
})
```

This worked for me since `$rootScope` and `$scope` are instances of `Scope`, and from what I understand, the run phase goes before controller instantiation (if this isn't the case, please correct me)

But yeah, would appreciate a smarter/cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: I'm convinced you could simply do `$rootScope.i18nService = i18nService;`. However, I don't recommend you to do so, as it's not a good practice. If you need something on a template - use directives or filters. If you need something in a controller - inject it directly.

Comment: @SergeyGoliney oh shit, you're actually right lol, I didn't know that $scope was atually inherited from $rootScope, but this does make sense, I feel dumb for not trying it before. Well, the editor I use has some good highlights for angular expressions, so I prefer reading it over than having it on directives, also, I quite often need it inside the controller.